# D3 scatterplot on time series multi-line line graph

Tags: d3.js, time-series, ellipse

I've attempted to place points (eventually with hover tooltips) at each data point on a time-series graph. [Here is the D3 Block](http://bl.ocks.org/jonmitten/f89f09c96146fa27dc089269b4b069d5)

The multi-line portion is based on [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/basilesimon/29efb0e0a43dde81985c20d9a862e34e), and creates a function called draw() which draws the graph leveraging external `d3.line()` generators.

I'm trying to create scatterplot dots on the data-points where temperature data and time intersect - which works on lines but not on my ellipses, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[The failing scatterplot attempt is here.](http://bl.ocks.org/jonmitten/b3337e022faab83c4073898911073d8e)

What's the best way to make the circles overlap the data-points? The error I'm getting in the JavaScript debugger is

```
d3.v4.js:1381 Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN".
d3.v4.js:1381 Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".
```

The data parsing seems to work fine with the line intersections, just not the cx and cy coordinates.

JavaScript for failing attempt is below:

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%e %B");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);


var tempprobe_line = d3.line()
    .x( function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y( function(d) { return y(d.tempprobe); });

var high_threshold_line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d){ return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d){ return y(d.threshold_high); });

var low_threshold_line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d){
        return x(d.timestamp);
    })
    .y(function(d){
        return y(d.threshold_low);
    })


var ambient_line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d)
        { return x(d.timestamp);}
    )
    .y( function(d) {
        return y(d.ambient);
    });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


function draw(data, tempdata) {

    var data = data[tempdata];

    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        d.timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
        d.tempprobe = +d.tempprobe;
        d.ambient = +d.ambient;
    });

    data.sort(function(a, b){
        return a["timestamp"]-b["timestamp"];
    });

    // scale the range of data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d.timestamp;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return Math.max(d.tempprobe, d.ambient);
    })]);

    // Add the tempprobe path.
    svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line temp-probe temperature")
        .attr("d", tempprobe_line);

    // Add the ambient path
    svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line ambient temperature")
        .attr("d", ambient_line);

    svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line high-threshold")
        .attr("d", high_threshold_line)

    svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line low-threshold")
        .attr("d", low_threshold_line)

    // add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+ height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    }

    d3.json("temp_data.json",
        function(error, data){
    if (error){
        throw error;
    }
    draw(data[0], "tempdata");
    // Add the scatterplot -- the failing part
    svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.tempprobe); });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are passing to the `selection.data()` function is wrong. The data you want is nested within the `data` variable.

This works for me:

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
   .data(data[0]['tempdata'])
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("r", 3.5)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.tempprobe); });
```

This adds circles over each data point on the blue `tempprobe` line.

Comment: Can somebody explain what the pattern used for generating lines is a.) called? and b.) how I can replicate that methodology for generating circles (dots) as the scatter plot? If I need to open a new question, I'm happy to, but I'd like to at least use the correct pattern name.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. It just looks like you're defining the line-drawing logic in a function, and then calling that with your data. I think the important thing is to understand what data object each call to `.data` should take. If it helps, I find using Chrome Devtools and making break-points to inspect variables at various points can be really instructive.